Яке походження прізвища Одокій?
Все що знайшов, то це походження від жіночого імені Євдокія зі спрощенням звуку "єв" на "о", якось притягнуте за волосся. Дехто посилається на церковне/християнське походження, але окрім походження від, і знов та сама, Євдокія Іліопольська.
Чи може хтось допоможе з цим питанням?

Грецьке походження здається виправданим.
Грецький префікс εὐ- ("добро-") в українській мові цілком міг пройти спрощення /єв-/ → /о-/ :

Євдокія (εὐδοκία "добра+справа") → Одокія
Євстафій (εὐσταθής = "добро+стійкий") → Остап.

Є ще одне ім'я грецького походження, де фігурує інший префікс αύ-, який так само спрощується до → /о-/ :

Авксентій (αύξέντιος = "звеличую") → Оксен.

З іншого боку, вочевидь, не всі подібні імена пройшли спрощення, як-то Євген/Євгеній ευγένιος та більш рідкісні Єфросинія/Євфросинія, Євпраксія, Євлампій зберегли префікс єв-.
Цікаво також ім'я Євфимій (Εὐθύμιος): чоловіче ім'я Юхим змінило префікс на /ю-/, а жіноче Химка цей префікс втратило.
Такі спрощення голосних не виглядають чимось незвичним в інших мовах.
Наприклад, ми не дивуємося, що Євклід (Εὐκλείδης) англійською читається [ˈjuːklɪd] (/'ю-клід/), а Євген — [juːˈdʒiːn] (/ю-'джін/).
